# Successor constraints fail when pickup and delivery is enabled

Tags: or-tools

I want to solve a VRP with pickups and deliveries. In addition I have some successor constraints that specify that a stop must follow another stop. For example:

- stop 1 is the pickup for stop 2
- stop 3 must be serviced immediately after stop 2

The pickup-dropoff constraints work as described in the examples. To implement the successor constraint I made three attempts:

- `cpsolver.Add(routing_model.NextVar(2) == 3)`
- `cpsolver.Add(cpsolver.MemberCt(routing_model.NextVar(2), [3]))`
- `routing_model.NextVar(2).SetValue(3)`

All attempts result in `assignment == None` if `routing_model.AddPickupAndDelivery(1, 2)` is added and there are at least two vehicles.
All attempts find a solution if `routing_model.AddPickupAndDelivery(1, 2)` is not added.

```py
n_stops = 4
n_vehicles = 2
ix_depot = 0

index_manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(n_stops, n_vehicles, ix_depot)
routing_model = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(index_manager)
cpsolver = routing_model.solver()

routing_model.AddPickupAndDelivery(1, 2)
cpsolver.Add(routing_model.NextVar(1) == 2)
cpsolver.Add(routing_model.NextVar(2) == 3)

assignment = routing_model.Solve()
print(assignment)

>>> None
```

What is going on here? How to best implement successor constraints?